# Getting value from a range input (slider)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, range, event-delegation

I am adding a slider dynamically on a page using a string like the one below:

```
"<input type=\"range\" name=\"aName\" min=\"1\" max=\"9\"/>";
```

Then, after I append it to the page using plain javascript I can delegate using the following code:

```
$('input[name=aName]').on('change', function () { alert(this.value)});
```

and indeed when the value changes, I receive the alert with the correct value. However, if I delegate like this:

```
$('input[name=aName]').on('change', handleChange);
```

and define the function later on like this:

```
function handleChange () {
    var theValue = $('input[name=aName]').value;
    alert("value: " + theValue);
}
```

I receive the alert with the message "value: undefined". Why is this thing happening?

Comment: what is `handleChange`? there is only `handleRQTSliderChange `

Comment: That was a mistake on my side. Clearly it is handleChange in both cases. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong `$('input[name=aName]').value`. I think you're mixing javascript & jquery.

For getting the value, use like this.

```
$('input[name=aName]').val()
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I thought I had tried this one as well, but apparently I did not. I will accept as soon as the system allows me.